# Id of created resource not in response header

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

When I POST a new entry to my end-point running Django REST Framework, the response 201 doesn't contain the newly created id/pk of the entry. I've read that a REST service is supposed to contain a link to the new resource in the `Location` header?

How can I achieve this?

I'm making some integrations and would like to be able to request the newly created resource right away, without further ado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of view you are using, you can either:

- manually build the `Response` so that it includes the newly created resource.
- rely on `create(request, *args, **kwargs)` provided by `CreateModelMixin`

I think the easiest way to achieve what you are looking for is to use the `CreateAPIView`. According to the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/),

> If an object is created this returns a 201 Created response, with a
>   serialized representation of the object as the body of the response.
>   If the representation contains a key named url, then the Location
>   header of the response will be populated with that value.

So this generic view for sure returns the data in the body of each response, but if you are interested in getting a **url** for each of your resources, you should probably take a look at [HyperlinkedModelSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#hyperlinkedmodelserializer). Those serializers work basically like the `ModelSerializer` except that they include a `url` field in the representation of each object, allowing you to browse through the resources.

Also if you are only interested in getting the `id/pk` of each created object, I think  `ModelSerializer` sets an `id` field by default for each representation that corresponds to the actual `pk` in the database. Not sure of that, but if it is not the case you can still explicitly ask for it by specifying the fields to be serialized, namely

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'color',)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! In my use case, it was as simple as adding `'id'` to `fields` in the serializer class.